# How to connect a data USB port on a device (designed for connecting flash drive to extract data) to a computer?

Tags: javascript, data-extraction, data-transfer, usb-drive

I have a Hi-pot tester (used for testing electrical equipment) that has a USB port to extract data after testing. Is there a way to connect this port directly to a computer? Can the data transfer event be caught?

I am trying to build a Javascript client that will upload the data to an API after each test.

The manual of the tester is in the following link:
https://www.elstar.com/images/PowerSupplies/ARI/Hypot_38xx/Hypot_V1.02-LowRes.pdf

I expect the USB port can be connected to a USB-C port on my computer since USB-C can act as a source and sink. The second option is to use a bridge-type USB male-male cable (used for transferring files between computers). I have not tried any of these options since this is for a company computer, so I can't take the risk.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. You cannot use the "*(7) Data USB port: this USB style port allows for connecting a USB flash drive to extract test and system data.*" to directly connect a computer.

However, you can use the "*(2) USB connector: USB port for serial communication. Refer to Appendix D: Remove bus interface*" on the rear panel of the device, this one is explicitly meant to be connected to a computer. Use a normal cable with USB-A and USB-B plugs.

As for using JavaScript to write programs, this is certainly possible for a standalone (node.js) application. For accessing serial ports from the browser, there is an experimental [Web Serial API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API).